# @include sweetalert via laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I was reading [sweet-alert](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert) README.md file when i saw this peace of code which is using laravel blade @include directive to call the swal function using the data stored in the session, and i was wondering how it works? what does the `::` mean?
here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Include this in your blade layout -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    @include('sweet::alert')
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for namespaced views, or views for packages.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Package Development - Views](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#views)

Comment: Thanks! I understand  now.